# How to switch from one wifi network to another wifi in appium(Android&IOS)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Currently i'm working in Banking application for accessing security servers i have to switch one wifi network to another wifi is there any possible way in appium.

Anyone please help me on this

Comment: Appium doesn't provide any api to switch between the wifi. If your device is rooted, you can use adb command to switch beetween wifi networks. You can also use the party app that can help you switch network.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Appium Studio. With which you can automate the process of switching from one wifi to another wifi channel.

You can find [here](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+setNetworkConnection) on how to switch on the wifi in a single command.
But to change the wifi network, you have to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a workaround in android to connect to particular wifi.

**Below are the steps:**

1. Navigate to Settings-Wifi Screen.
2. Tap on the wifi-name.

**Step1:** Navigate to Settings-Wifi Screen.

**For Windows OS:**

```
String allCommand = null;
String commandForWifiSettings="am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings";
allCommand = "cmd.exe /C adb -s " + deviceID + " " + commandForWifiSettings;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(allCommand);
```

**For Linux OS:**

```
String allCommand = null;
String commandForWifiSettings="am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings";
allCommand = "/bin/bash -l -c adb -s " + deviceID + " " + commandForWifiSettings;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(allCommand);
```

**Step2:** Tap on the wifi-name in the wifi-settings screen. Add some wait before tapping on the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Wifi-name']").click();
```